# Django looking for wrong path on url() in css files

Tags: css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set up a personal blog that uses Django and is hosted in Heroku. You can check it here: https://generic-blog.herokuapp.com/

All my static files were loading as intended on my local machine until I decided to store the static files on AWS S3. I configured my settings.py to use S3 and did `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect the static files to my s3 bucket. The static files are loading as intended, but on my css files there are url() with relative paths as this one:

```
url("../fonts/blog.woff") format("woff")
```

Which is not loading, as the path is incorrect. My browser's console gives me the following error:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "blog" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2147746065 source: https://personal-django-blogs.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/blog.woff
```

The path that Django tries to search for the font is wrong `https://personal-django-blogs.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/blog.woff` would have to be `https://personal-django-blogs.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/static_root/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff`

I could just replace each relative path with the absolute path of the file in s3 bucket, but this feels wrong. I think the problem lies in settings.py, but I couldn't manage to understand why when working on s3 the relative paths don't work anymore.

Here's my settings.py relevant configurations:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]
# Path to venv
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

# Path for collectstatic to store files
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')

# User uploaded files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'blog.s3_storages.MediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS [url()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()) is not processed by Django static files but called directly from Browser

As you are using relative path resolved path value is expected. You will need to have some preprocessing of this CSS file to set the bucket name to URL if you have multiple deployments of it or just set it to absolute bucket path

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One thing that still confuses me is why in local development the relative paths works as intended and not just 127.0.0.1/fonts/blog.woff as in development