# django not able to load static fonts

Tags: django

The page is not loading the fonts, I'm not sure why. The fonts are located in the static folder, the CSS is ok. Does anyone have a similar experience?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/icon.png' %}" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel ='stylesheet' href = "{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65581187/django-looking-for-wrong-path-on-url-in-css-files/65581364#65581364

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't load the .ttf inside css, only

````
font-family: "CustomFont";
src: url("https://yoursite.com/css/fonts/CustomFont.eot");
src: url("https://yoursite.com/css/fonts/CustomFont.woff") format("woff"),
url("https://yoursite.com/css/fonts/CustomFont.otf") format("opentype"),
url("https://yoursite.com/css/fonts/CustomFont.svg#filename") format("svg");
}```
````

Comment: I found the solution..
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Numbers';
    src: url("../fonts//LibreBaskerville-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');